# Python Popen writing command prompt output to logfile

Tags: python, logging, popen, python-logging

Firstly I am running this Python script on Windows.

I am trying to open a new command prompt window every time and want to execute a .exe with some arguments. After I execute, I want to copy the command prompt output to a log file. I created a log file at the location say "log.log". When I run the script, it doesn't seem to write the contents to the log file at all.

The coreServerFullPath is like `C:\Users\nanduk\Desktop\SourceCode\Core\CoreServer\Server\CoreServer\bin\Debug`

And here in this location I created a blank text document and named it to log.log

```
def OpenCoreServer():
    os.chdir(coreServerFullPath)
    #logging.basicConfig(filename="log.log", level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('your text goes here') #I see this line in the log.
    result = subprocess.Popen('start cmd /k "CoreServer.exe -c -s" >> log.log 2>&1', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    time.sleep(4)
    print("ABCD")
    with open('log.log', 'r') as logg:
        print(logg.read())
```

Comment: Why do you do `logging.basicConfig()` to the same file at all? That doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: I took out the line and it doesn't write anything to the file.

Comment: That's not what I asked, but right, if you don't need Python's logging system, don't configure it, especially not into the same file. Anyway: (a) You're not waiting for the process to finish at all (b) You're using UNIX style redirections; might not work on Windows. (c) You're piping stdout/stderr and never reading them; that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get away with something like

```
import subprocess
import time

os.chdir(coreServerFullPath)
with open("log.log", "ab") as log:
    proc = subprocess.Popen("CoreServer.exe", stdout=log, stderr=log)
    while proc.poll() is None:
        # Do something while the process is running
        time.sleep(1)
    print("CoreServer exited with code", proc.returncode)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. I will try find a way to write that output to the console.